# Indexing of mega shared folder Link in heroku

Tags: heroku, indexing, cloud, cloud-storage, rclone

I want to do indexing of the mega shared folder in Heroku
[ it is the same as indexing of the google drive folder in Heroku App ]
Is there any way to do that?

Tips:

1. I think rclone can do that
2. here is the GitHub link
   https://github.com/developeranaz/Mega-index-heroku
   this GitHub requires login credentials of mega cloud to get indexed for single account in Heroku

I want
Either multiple account indexing to Heroku should be there
Or multiple shared folder indexing to Heroku should be there
[ Any of the one solutions will be best ]